# Use <optgroup> with form.fields.queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset

Is it possible to set a form's ForeignKey field's queryset so that it will take separate queryset's and output them in `<optgroup>`'s?

Here is what I have:

views.py

```
form = TemplateFormBasic(initial={'template': digest.template.id})
form.fields['template'].queryset = Template.objects.filter(Q(default=1) | Q(user=request.user)).order_by('name')
```

In my Template model, I have default Templates and User-created templates.  I want them to be visibly separated in the `<select>` box eg.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Default Templates">
    <option>Default 1</option>
    <option>Default 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="User Templates">
    <option>User Template 1</option>
    <option>User Template 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using the example given on [this blog](http://dealingit.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/django-tip-showing-optgroup-in-a-modelform/)

views.py

```
form.fields['template'].choices = templates_as_choices(request)

def templates_as_choices(request):
    templates = []
    default = []
    user = []
    for template in Template.objects.filter(default=1).order_by('name'):
        default.append([template.id, template.name])

    for template in Template.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('name'):
        user.append([template.id, template.name])

    templates.append(['Default Templates', default])
    templates.append(['User Templates', user])

    return templates
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what the Dr. Ordered! I was looking for a way to manipualate form.fields['field'].queryset into something custom and .choices completely slipped my mind. Great!

Answer (score 4):

I've done in the past by not using a foreign key on the form, but rather a [charfield with choices](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/choices/).

A CharField with choices support optgroups. You need to have the choices in this format:

> ('Group 1',(('1','Yada'),('2','Yada'))), ('Group 2',(('3','Bepety'),('4','Bopity')))

Choices can also be a callable. So I created my own function that traverses the models and builds a tuple like the above.